# Upload multiple files via AngularJS to Laravel Controller

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

---

## I have

[image]

## Browse files button

```
<input type="file" upload-files multiple />
```

## Create Button

```
<button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="store()" >Create</button>
```

---

## Directive

```
myApp.directive('uploadFiles', function () {
    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('change', function (event) {
                var files = event.target.files;
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    scope.$emit("seletedFile", { file: files[i] });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

---

## Listen for the file selected

```
$scope.files = [];
$scope.$on("seletedFile", function (event, args) {

    console.log("event is ", event);
    console.log("args is ", args);

    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.files.push(args.file);
    });

});
```

---

## Post data and selected files.

```
$scope.store = function() {

    $scope.model = {
      name: $scope.name,
      type: $scope.type
    };

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/image/store',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
        transformRequest: function (data) {
            console.log("data coming into the transform is ", data);
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("model", angular.toJson(data.model));
            for (var i = 0; i < data.files; i++) {
                formData.append("file" + i, data.files[i]);
            }
            return formData;
        },

        data: { model: $scope.model, files: $scope.files }

    })


    .then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log("%cSuccess!", "color: green;");
        console.log(response);
        $scope.refresh();
        $scope.showModal = false;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log("%cError", "color: red;");
        console.log(response);
    });
};
```

---

## Result

In my console, I don't see my files got pass on to my controller in the back-end.

```
array:1 [
  "model" => "{"type":"wedding"}"
]
```

---

## Questions

What steps did I forget?

**How would one go about and debug this further ?**

---

Comment: For the time being, as an alternative of course, you can use https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Answer (score 2):

I've done several angular 1 projects and also find it is not simple to upload files via $http api. Hope below code snippet which i used in my projects may help you.

```
$scope.store = function() {
  var formData = new FormData();

  // add normal properties, the name should be the same as
  // what you would use in a html form
  formData.append('model[name]', $scope.name);
  formData.append('model[type]', $scope.type);

  // add files to form data.
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.files; i++) {
    formData.append('file' + i, $scope.files[i]);
  }

  // Don't forget the config object below
  $http.post('/image/store', formData, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
  }).then(function() {
    // ...
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here some suggestions for you:

1. Make the `Content-type` sets to `multipart/form-data` to set the content type to something like.... "it has some part in it, please make sure you get it properly" thing.
2. Use Axios. Here's a working examples (if you didn't use Axios, this example are good too). [Example to Axios on Uploading File](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/blob/master/examples/upload/index.html).

Comment: I updated my `headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },` --> `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },` - still didn't work.

Comment: Can we see your PHP script too?

Answer (score 1):

You can use FormData instead

```
var formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('model[var]', $scope.var);

  // For add to the FormData other file
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.files; i++) {
    formData.append('file' + i, $scope.files[i]);
  }

 // POST REQUEST MUST BE:
  $http.post('url', formData, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,  //It is for allowing files
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    }).then(function(response) 
  {
    // verify if response get 200
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not very experienced in Angular, so I'm assuming that your front-end works.

**Debugging Tip** Create a PHP file called...I dunno...*file_dump.php*. In that file, put this code:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>"
    print_r($_REQUEST)
    echo "</pre>"
?>
```

and submit your form to that. That will show you all your request data. If you do not see your files in the output, it is a problem with your JavaScript. Since I am not that good at Angular, I'm going to point you to this link: [link to multiple file upload tutorial using Angular](http://www.encodedna.com/angularjs/tutorial/angularjs-multiple-file-upload-example-with-webapi.htm).
These guys seem to know what they're doing.

If you do see your files in the *file_dump.php* output, it's a problem with your backend - Laravel. This, I *can* help you with, but I need to see your scripts for me to be helpful in this aspect.

Please do post the results of *file_dump.php*.

Also, are you using the correct methods for fetching files? [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files). If not, then we have found our culprit...

=D
Pranav

Answer (score 1):

**It is my directive:**

```
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', 'message', function ($parse, message) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            //This part is for validate file type in current case must be image
            element.bind('change', function (e) {
                if (attrs.onlyImages == 'true') {
                    if (element[0].files[0].name.substring(element[0].files[0].name.lastIndexOf('.')) != '.jpg'
                        && element[0].files[0].name.substring(element[0].files[0].name.lastIndexOf('.')) != '.jpeg'
                        && element[0].files[0].name.substring(element[0].files[0].name.lastIndexOf('.')) != '.png'
                        && element[0].files[0].name.substring(element[0].files[0].name.lastIndexOf('.')) != '.gif'
                        && element[0].files[0].name.substring(element[0].files[0].name.lastIndexOf('.')) != '.bmp'
                    ) {
                        message.error("This field only accept files of type images(jpg,png)");
                        element.attr('is_valid', false);
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        element.attr('is_valid', true);
                    }
                }
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

**the html:**

```
<input type="file" only-images="true" file-model="data.image" >
```

And Js Controller fragment:

```
 var fd = new FormData();
 fd.append('fileImage', data.image);

 $http.post('http://url.com', fd, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined,}
            })
```

On laravel to get and copy image: is clear on the docs

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files